# loopbackjs and Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, loopback

How do I implement Angular Material in loopback?

I installed angular material via NPM. My app.js looks like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myItems", ['lbServices']);
```

My question is, where must I include the angular material code?

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

Comment: I've no experience with loopback, but i don't understand the need for material-ui in a backend component / rest-api? In the Angular frontend it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

loopback use angularJs framework. If you want add any library, you can add library using script tag in index.html. For material design you can use angularjs material . Please follow this link to install and use https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started.